# Can the university you work for or study at protect your identity by listing you under a pseudonym?

Tags: publications, privacy

Some people have reasons to want their identity protected from a Google search, such as a dangerous stalker ex-spouse.

When you become a grad student, assistant professor, etc. at a university, and if the university wants to put your name on their website (directory, course catalog, departmental page, to name a few), can you refuse it or have them at least put out a pseudonym instead, assuming you have been publishing or contributing to articles (or intend to) with that pseudonym?

Comment: Ask your school. Many will offer the option of not listing you at all, but I've never heard of a pseudonym option and I'm not sure why you'd want it rather than simple non-publication.

Comment: @keshlam: "simple non-publication" doesn't actually sound that simple as soon as you get some tasks that require you to be findable by strangers.

Comment: It's really not only a question of the university, but of your whole academic existence. You will need to publish and list an affiliation. If you use your real name and your actual affiliation, there goes your anonymity. But how many journals/conferences will allow you to publish without giving an affiliation? And even if that works, it will be easy for the stalker to socially engineer your affiliation out of them - all it needs is one helpful administrative assistant. Sadly, the only possibility I see for a stalked academic is a complete legal change of name.

Comment: @stephankolassa has a good point... If you need to be invisible but findable the only idea I have is delist but make sure all publications list what lab did the work so you can be found that way. Working with your school is still the only way to make it happen. Good luck.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: Well, you *could* use a pseudonym for your academic website and use only that for publishing, while listing the actual affiliation. Of course, the pseudonym should not be linked to a photo. But no-one ever verifies whether the people indicated as authors of a paper during the submission process actually exist. It could work in universities where the ties between the HR department (handling the actual name) and the people responsible for the staff websites (only entering the pseudonym data) aren't too tight.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - problem: now you have published under a pseudonym, and you go to a conference. Do you go under your real name, and people can't link your papers to your name tag and your presentation? Or do you attend under your pseudonym? That may be possible, but you may need to do some explaining, as to why your name tag says "Student", but the credit card you pay your fee with says "Gosset". A few things could go wrong here.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: I don't quite see that problem; you'd always go under your pseudonym. No-one claims you have to pay the fee yourself, with your own credit card. Paying for colleagues doesn't strike me as unusual. You may have to use your real name in your hotel, but then, I've never had a problem staying away from the conference hotels and finding another nearby hotel, where I'm usually the only conference attendee.

Answer (score 11):

This is commonly done in several types of cases:

- by women who want to retain using their maiden name professionally while switching their legal name to their husbands
- by students from countries who have taken a hostile stance towards the United States and who want to protect their extended families back in their home country
- By foreigners with impossibly long (from an American standpoint) first or last names or who use non-mainstream variations on their name
- By faculty who go by their middle names or nicknames not their formal first names
- By aforementioned stalking victims

If you are at a large enough institution, they are prepared to handle these types of situations. My (large enough) institution has the following:

1. Fields in the university directory database that allow for 'nicknames' to take the place of names. Because all of our e-mails are firstname.lastname@myschool.edu, this allows for e-mails to arrive properly.
2. Flags in the university directory that particular information should not be publicly released. One can prevent the listing altogether if you choose.
3. The only other place where names would appear would be the faculty/staff/student website, which is under departmental control and easily changed.

One of the doctoral students that I work for is from one of the aforementioned hostile countries and you will not find any web presence for her on the departmental website.

This gets trickier when you are faculty, as students need to enroll in your courses and you need to publish. I would recommend in this case either a full legal name change or pushing your university/department to recognize a pseudonym. It helps greatly if you have a common last name and only need to modify your first name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to accept the reality that this is not practically possible. Your name will appear on dozens of websites in various ways -- your own website, your department's website, the university's website for news and announcements, the university's class catalog for the current and previous years, the university's records of external grants funded, the university's accreditation reports that include publication lists, your university's open records disclosures of state employee salaries to open websites, etc etc etc. This will, in all practicality, involve dozens of people who take your name from electronic databases, paper records, payroll systems. Many websites will be automatically generated as well from electronic databases. Even if state law gives you the right to opt out of something like this, you will almost certainly find it impossible to actually do so in practice given that you have no idea where all your name is listed and who to contact to get it removed or changed. You also have to balance this with the university's very reasonable interest in allowing students to find information (such as teaching schedule, website, course information, etc) about their teacher.

I don't really think you have any other options than legally change your name permanently.

Comment: That may be place-specific, and maybe the institutions you are familiar with have a very high degree of automation - in some places, it rather seems like the HR-related matters are entirely disjoint from the whole publicly viewable part of the university. That is, the HR department and the agency that does payments has to have an employee's real name, but other than that? Employees have to set up their own websites and add themselves to the listings on the department websites (or they have to ask administrators to do so for them, based on the data the employees provide), the class ...

Comment: ... catalog is written by each department based on the information provided individually by each of the employees, and - up to a certain level - salaries are standardized based on nationally valid tables, so there is no public listing of who works at the university (that sounds like violating privacy laws in some places, anyway). I'm not claiming an employee could pull that off on their own, but as long as the head of the group and similarly administrative persons (who may deal with HR and payment departments and who might have access to internal staff tables) are informed, it *might* work.

Comment: I think it would be a Herculean task. I would also think that the number of places where students still enroll using websites hand-crafted by departments rapidly converges to zero. It is so much more efficient to have processes like enrollment, grade management, online homework, etc, done centrally that whoever isn't doing it that way is almost certainly thinking very hard about doing it centrally. All of these in one way or another require university-wide databases.

Comment: Sure, no opposition to that. Universities whose processes I have seen invariably used such databases. It's just that they usually kept all of those databases strictly separate from anything that ever becomes publicly visible.